# How to read oracle db over vpn from azure databricks?

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

When I try to read a oracle table via azure databricks(I connect to vpn for accessing this db) , it shows below error

Java. Sql. Sqlrecoverableexception : IO Error : The network adapter could not establish the connection..

Do I need to specify the VPN details in databricks?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you connected to VPN, the Databricks cluster that is running in the cloud couldn't reach your on-premise Oracle installation.  To achieve that you need to work with your networking team on setting VPN connection between on-premise & cloud.  It's described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network) in great details, so it doesn't make sense to repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hostnames which are being used in the Databricks clusters should be enabled to  access on-prem resources through Endpoint Services.You can ref : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network)